# How can we add div/main tags while creating sitecore forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

I started working on a sitecore form however there are no tags available which I need to add, for example div tags , main tag. Please let me know how this can be achieved.

For example if I want this dummy html for now say two or three inherit divs in a main tag, how can we achieve that. If someone has worked on this they must be knowing, any links or if any customization needed those links would also work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Sitecore Forms Extension` if you are looking to add `HTML tags`, as that contains the **RawHtml** field which would serve your purpose. See the answer here [how-to-add-rich-text-to-sitecore-forms](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14289/how-to-add-rich-text-to-sitecore-forms?rq=1):

You will also find a link there for creating any custom fields if needed.